# Key press with javascript python selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, click, sendkeys

Is there a way to basically simulate key pressing from a keyboard?

I want to click an element that's typable and then mimic what an end-user would do to type, by pressing keys. I don't want to give any XPath and then use sendkeys or anything.

Bascially element.click() -> keypressing, I'm pretty sure selenium has no option for this that's why I'm turning to js. Does anyone know if something like this is possible?

EDIT: The test is done on a webpage

Can this be done?

Comment: Do you want basically something like simulate writting on a text-box?

Comment: Basically, yes I got a nasty bug that if I use sendkeys() it moves to the next page, and it's not reproduceble manually, typing from the keyboard, so i want to somehow mimic what i'm doing manually, which is click on the textbox then type (simulate keys as u describe it)

Comment: driver.find_element_by_YOUR_CHOOSE_('your_choose').click()

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=click

Comment: Mate, click method wasn't an issue here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'll need to obtain the element (use XPath or CSS_Selector).

You can accomplish this with [`ActionChains`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html) for instance if you want to copy/paste text use CTRL+'c' then CTRL+'v':

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('http://example.com')
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('the/xpath')

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click(element).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('v').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

Or you can use [`ActionChains().send_keys()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.send_keys)